# How can I hide Form2 using a button from Form1?

Tags: c#

I have two windows forms, Form1 and Form2. In Form1 I have two buttons: "show form 2" and "hide form 2". When I press "show form 2", it shows the second form. But I don't know how to hide the second form when I press "hide form 2". Any ideas?

Comment: Keep a reference to form2 so that you can call Close() on it.

Comment: You need an instance of form2 in form1.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

If **Form2** is open you can access it by:

```
Form form2 = Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
```

And then inside button click event, call:

```
form2.Hide();
```